# Relay OAuth2 Bearer token with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, backend, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on a service that will accept an **OAuth2 Bearer token** and validate the token then relay that token to other **backend** services.

I can pull the token from the request and pass it along, but is there anything already in Spring's OAuth2 support for retrieving a token from the request and passing it along?

Or should I create a custom **OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails** and **OAuth2ClientContext** to handle this?

Comment: Have you looked to Scribe library - https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava